# How to redirect to specific location after registration with Passport.js and Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, passport.js

I'm using Sails.js, and I've installed the `passport` and `passport-local` modules, for local authentication.

When I installed the passport module, some files were created automatically, under policies, services, models and controllers. I've modified some of these files to fit my needs, however, I can't find a way  to redirect an user to certain location specifically after he registers.

Right now, the default behaviour is that the user registers and is automatically authenticated and then redirected to the same url that an user gets redirected to when he/she logs in.

I've tried to look into the different passport generated files, but I can't find a "registration callback" or something similar. In the `AuthController`, there's a "callback" method that looks like this:

```
  callback: function (req, res) {
    function tryAgain (err) {
      var flashError = req.flash('error')[0];

      if (err && !flashError ) {
        req.flash('error', 'Error.Passport.Generic');
      } else if (flashError) {
        req.flash('error', flashError);
      }
      req.flash('form', req.body);

      var action = req.param('action');

      switch (action) {
        case 'register':
          res.redirect('/signup');
          break;
        case 'disconnect':
          res.redirect('back');
          break;
        default:
          res.redirect('/login');
      }
    }

    passport.callback(req, res, function (err, user) {
      if (err) {
        return tryAgain();
      }

      req.login(user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return tryAgain();
        }

        res.redirect('/');
      });
    });
  },
```

However, this only applies to when the user is authenticated (login), I think.
I think the answer may lie under the passport file over at the services folder, but I'm not sure. I don't really fully understand the code yet.

I'm just looking for the right place to even place this code, since I have no clue. So, **how can I redirect an user to a specific location after he has registered? (But ONLY after that)**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this is the best way do to it, but I found it to be quite simple; this is what I did, in case anyone finds themselves under a similar situation with a similar setup.

Under `api/services/protocols/local.js`, there is a method named `exports.register`; within that method, and just before `next()` is called, declare a property `isNew` to `user`, like this:

```
user.isNew = true;
```

Then, in the `callback` method of the `AuthController`, under the controllers folder, `isNew` will be available (and set to `true`) as `req.user.isNew`, if the user just registered, and that way, you can do your logic with that, before `res.redirect` is called. So, something like this (within that method):

```
if(req.user.isNew) {
    return res.redirect('/welcomePage');
}
return res.redirect('/dashboard');
```

And that's it.